# Errors naming matrix columns - array length does not match and unused arguments

Tags: r, matrix

I managed to create a test matrix naming the rows and columns with something like this:

```
my_matrix3<-matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE,dimnames=c("row1", "row2", "row3"),c("col1","col2", "col3"))
```

Then I went back to run it again, and the output was that the colname arguments were unused.

The other (original) error is "'dimnames'[2] not equal to array" when labeling colnames with strsplit words (both listed and unlisted). The length of the word vector does match the number of columns of the new matrix. What could be going wrong ?

```
DTM<-matrix(0,nrow=length(text), ncol=length(dictionary))
colnames(DTM)<-list(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `list` with `dimnames`

```
my_matrix3 <-
  matrix(
    data = 0,
    nrow = 3,
    ncol = 3,
    byrow = TRUE,
    dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3"),c("col1","col2", "col3"))
    )


my_matrix3

     col1 col2 col3
row1    0    0    0
row2    0    0    0
row3    0    0    0
```

Comment: Sorry, yea, I was testing out if I had to use list and completely spaced that it *is* necessary. What do you think about the other code ?

Comment: Could provide a sample of your data?

Comment: It seems that I simply did not need to use the list function to assign column names. Basically, I got it backwards. List is needed for dimnames but not for colnames.